# Trouble aligning Graphics with Image

Tags: graphics, image, drawing

I import the test image eloquently named "Tank2":

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tank2"}]
```

And do an *extremly poor* corner detection:

```
GetCorners[img_] :=
  Module[{
    filtered = ImageConvolve[GaussianFilter[img, 1.1], ( {
        {0, -1, 0},
        {-1, 4, -1},
        {0, -1, 0}
       } )]
    },
   ImageValuePositions[filtered // ImageAdjust, White, 0.5]
   ];
```

Now I want to overlay the "corners" as small circles, and do this:

```
g = Graphics[{{Red, Circle[#1, 1]} & /@ GetCorners[img]}, 
  ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img], PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio[img]]
ImageCompose[img, g]
```

Alas, the result is not aligned, as you can see below, what to do? Is there a better way to draw "on top" of an image? I guess the Graphics function pads the image in some way, then crops it with the wrong midpoint?

[image: Poor image of a tank and a very bad corner detection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[img, Graphics@{Red, Point@GetCorners[img]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, that's much more terse than mine. Upvote for that.

Comment: @Skurmedel Mixing images and graphics need some practice. Usually the most obvious thing works. But when it doesn't you're in a dangerous terrain.

Comment: That terrain does look dangerous, with the tank and all :-p

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my own problem :), I used `Show[img, g]`, which did the business.