# Wrong Graphics coordinate system after Image to Graphics conversion

Tags: graphics, bugs, image-processing, image, conversion

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.3.1** [CASE:4896512]

---

If I upload this image (originally this `img` was generated by `EdgeDetect`) by normal workflow [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Syw.png), this phenomenon will disappear. So I had to wrap all `img` information in code to make sure the problem would be reproduced.

```
img=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOOi1.png"],"Byte"]]]];
Show[img,Axes->True]
```

[image]

But note the dimensions:

```
ImageDimensions[img]
```

> {709, 251}

Apparently, I got a wrong coordinate system, which will cause a scaling effect on the coordinates of the results identified by some functions (such as `ComponentMeasurements`). I had to do this to avoid this mistake:

```
Show[Image[ImageData[img]], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

I am currently on version 13, why do I have this problem? Is this a bug?

Comment: It gives the same in 12.3.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I reproduce the issue with version 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Apparently, the issue arises due to a non-default value of `ImageResolution` option of `img`:

```
Options[img, ImageResolution]
```

> ```
> {ImageResolution -> {96., 96.}}
> ```

Setting this option to `Automatic`:

```
Show[Image[img, ImageResolution -> Automatic], Axes -> True]
```

> [image: output]

```
Options[%, PlotRange]
```

> ```
> {PlotRange -> {{0, 709.}, {0, 251.}}}
> ```

According to "Details" section of the Documentation [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResolution.html) for `ImageResolution`,

> The default setting `ImageResolution->Automatic` typically uses a resolution of 72 dpi for bitmap graphics formats.

Let us check:

```
Show[Image[img, ImageResolution -> {72, 72}], Axes -> True]
Options[%, PlotRange]
```

> [image: output]

> ```
> {PlotRange -> {{0, 709.}, {0, 251.}}}
> ```

We have got exactly the same data inside of the `Graphics` object. The only exception is that inside of `Raster` now we have explicit value of the `ImageResolution` option (which isn't a documented option for `Raster`!):

```
Show[Image[img, ImageResolution -> {72, 72}], Axes -> True] // 
 ResourceFunction["ShortInputForm"]
```

> [image: screenshot]

But for what this options is kept inside of `Raster`? Let us check how the backward conversion to `Image` works:

```
Show[Image[img, ImageResolution -> {72, 72}], Axes -> True] // First // Image // Options
```

> ```
> {ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageResolution -> {72, 72}, Interleaving -> True}
> ```

We see that the backward conversion algorithm uses this option and sets it for produced `Image` object.

The same happens for the original `img`:

```
Show[img] // First // Image // Options
```

> ```
> {ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageResolution -> {96., 96.}, Interleaving -> True}
> ```

Hence what you have found seems to be an undocumented feature of the `Image` to `Graphics` conversion algorithm. Whether this behavior is justified, I'm not sure.

As you show, this feature results in inconsistency when combining the results of image-processing functions like `ComponentMeasurements` with `Graphics` obtained by the above conversion method:

```
cm = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[img], {"BoundingDiskCenter", "BoundingDiskRadius"}];
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Circle @@@ Values[cm]}]]
```

> [image: output]

This inconsistency is worth reporting to Wolfram. The above-described feature (I mean exactly `PlotRange` change upon `ImageResolution` change) is completely unnecessary for both `Image` to `Graphics` and `Raster` to `Image` conversion algorithms. I'm not sure for what it is introduced at all. In any case, worth reporting to Wolfram.

But notice that high-level `HighlightImage` doesn't have this feature:

```
hi = HighlightImage[img, Graphics[{Red, Circle @@@ Values[cm]}]]
Options[hi, {PlotRange, ImageSize, ImageSizeRaw}]
```

> [image: output]

> ```
> {PlotRange -> {{0, 709}, {0, 251}}, ImageSize -> {222., Automatic}, 
>  ImageSizeRaw -> {531.75, 188.25}}
> ```

```
Image[hi] // Options
```

> ```
> {ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageResolution -> 96., Interleaving -> True}
> ```

As we see, `HighlightImage` not only correctly understands `img` coordinates, but also sets the option `ImageSizeRaw` for produced `Graphics` object. This option may be used later when converting the result back into `Image` for computing the original `ImageResolution`. Here is how it can be used:

```
ImageResolution -> (72 *#[[1, All, 2]]/#[[2]]) &@
 Values[Options[hi, {PlotRange, ImageSizeRaw}]]
```

> ```
> ImageResolution -> {96., 96.}
> ```

(But currently, it isn't used and `ImageResolution` is taken directly from the `Image` embedded in produced `Graphics` as `Inset`! Notice also that the original `ImageSize` is lost when converting backward to `Image`!)

From these considerations we find another workaround:

```
HighlightImage[img, {}, Axes -> True]
```

> [image: output]

```
Options[%, {PlotRange, ImageSize, ImageSizeRaw}]
```

> ```
> {PlotRange -> {{0, 709}, {0, 251}}, ImageSize -> {222., Automatic}, 
>  ImageSizeRaw -> {531.75, 188.25}}
> ```

But again, I don't think that this justifies the `PlotRange` change when converting an `Image` with non-default `ImageResolution` into a `Graphics` object using `Show`. I see no reason for this feature. Even `HighlightImage` doesn't change `PlotRange`, which seems more consistent than the current behavior of `Show`.

---

I've wrote a *suggestion for improvement* on this issue to the support [CASE:4896512]. Here is the response:

> From your description, I gather you are noticing a regression with
> PlotRange getting changed per ImageResolution specifications for
> Image.
>
> I checked and reproduced your issue, and have passed along a report to
> our developers on the same. We are always interested in improving
> Mathematica and wish to thank you for bringing this issue to our
> attention.
>
> If you run into any other unexpected behavior with Mathematica, please
> do not hesitate to contact us in the future.

Hence the Wolfram support identifies this issue as a regression bug (I hadn't used such a term in my report).

Comment: Do you think I should add a bug tag to this post?

Comment: @yode I don't think it is a bug. Looks like just an undocumented feature of the `Image` to `Graphics` (and backward) conversion algorithm.

Comment: So do you think this is in line with the expected behavior? `Show[img,Graphics[{Red,Circle@@@Values[ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[img],{"BoundingDiskCenter","BoundingDiskRadius"}]]}]]`

Comment: @yode This is a good example. I updated the answer with further thoughts.

Comment: Do you mind if I add a bug tag now?

Comment: @yode You can add if you wish. But much more important is to report it to the support. You can report it as a bug due to the fact that it breaks many simple and elegant solutions which worked well for years, like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109695/280) one.

Comment: I think a proper tag can help readers understand the topic of the post quickly

Comment: @yode As a side note and supplement, I'd like to point out that both the numbers 72 and 96 are kind of "hard-coded" into Windows, but they are meant for different concepts. Quote [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels): *"One logical inch equals 96 pixels. Using this scaling factor, a 72-point font is rendered as 96 pixels tall."* Also note on Windows, because of compatibility, applications using different GUI frameworks end up having different scalings, which is a *huge* mess.

Comment: OTOH, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards), Mac OS doesn't suffer from this at all.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Is there any response from the official?

Comment: @yode Not yet. I'll update the answer and notify you when I get a response.

Comment: @yode I updated the answer with the response from the support.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Funny, `HighlightImage` will [change the imagesize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4OFq.png). I'm not sure if this is the same bug you submitted([CASE:4896512]).

Comment: @yode After `HighlightImage` you have `Graphics`, not `Image`. Hence applying `ImageDimensions` is incorrect.

Comment: The result is `Graphics` instead of `Image`, which is one of the problems in itself

Comment: Their [development documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXyBWuoUync&t=47m4s) shows that this feature will be adjusted