# How to get ImageResolution for the Image?

Tags: graphics, image

Is it possible to get (not change!) `ImageResolution` for an existing `Image`, say the one I have imported from a file?

`ImageResolution` does affect `Image`'s interaction with `Graphics` (it seems undocumented that `Show` works with `Image`s but it's very convenient):

```
Module[{img, dims},
 img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "F16"}];
 
 dims = ImageDimensions@img;
 GraphicsGrid@List@Table[Show[
     Image[img, ImageResolution -> res],
     Graphics[{
       Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, dims}],
       PointSize[Large], Point[dims/2.]
       }],
     Frame -> True,
     PlotLabel -> ImageDimensions[img]
     ]
    , {res, {$ImageResolution, 120}}
    ]
 ]
```

[image: different image resolutions in Show]

Comment: I find it easier to think in terms of image size in pixels when dealing with digital images on screen. To me, resolution must be associated with a print size to make sense (eg 300 dpi at 4x6" print size, or similar). Perhaps you could expand on what you want to achieve and how the resolution of the image would help you get there.

Comment: The idea is to make the image a background for the graphics. I already found the workaround — reset the image resolution to `$ImageResolution` every time when mixing with `Graphics`.

But the question is about accessing this data of the image. Surely, `Show` does access it somehow.

Comment: Strongly related: [Wrong Graphics coordinate system after Image to Graphics conversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262138/280).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

`resolveImageResolution[img_Image] := Replace[Information[img, "ImageResolution"], Automatic -> 72]`

That can return either a single value or a horizontal/vertical pair.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the value for Automatic will change in the future?

Comment: As @AlexeyPopkov said, the magic number 72 doesn't look very promising (considering `$ImageResolution` is `Automatic`.

Otherwise thanks for the answer!

Comment: `$ImageResolution` is used as the default value for `Rasterize`.  The FrontEnd is the one that actually resolves it to a value.  I doubt I will ever change that, since it has backward compatibility implications.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(An addition to the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264141/280) by [ihojnicki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18638/ihojnicki).)</sup>

> The idea is to make the image a background for the graphics.

`HighlightImage` is a built-in implementation of this idea:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "F16"}];
dims = ImageDimensions@img;
Table[HighlightImage[Image[img, ImageResolution -> res], 
  Graphics[{Black, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, dims}], PointSize[Large], 
    Point[dims/2.]}], Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> ImageDimensions[img]], {res, {$ImageResolution, 120}}]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Strongly related:

- [Wrong Graphics coordinate system after Image to Graphics conversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262138/280)